# email sending limits and buddypress / notifications

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, buddypress

We have a BuddyPress community website with about 400 members, all set to receive different emails at different frequencies.

- Some get an email notice every time something is posted to a certain message board and topic authors can subscribe to get replies by email.
- Some get emails when updates are posted to groups.
- Site admins can send out emails to the whole members list.
- And so on...

I'm concerned about email delivery and hosting sending limits.  We don't have the budget for a dedicated server, and most hosts even on a VPS set daily and/or hourly limits.  With each email being sent out to several hundred people at a time, those limits can get hit early in a day sometimes.

Obviously there are lots of sites like this that have thousands of members with all sorts of email notice options.  What are the ways to work around the sending limits?  I know it's smtp limits, does the build in wp_mail function not use smtp?

We're looking for a new host (from godaddy) and I want to make sure they can accomodate what we need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use free [wpMandrill](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/) plugin. After setting it up, all your emails will be sent via Mandrill, and you will have ability to see open/click info as well. Free account has 12000 emails to send during the month. That's a good start to see how it is going AND actually get a real numbers of how many emails you send per month.

Comment: This information is not up to date anymore as Mandrill doesn't have free accounts. Maybe Sendgrid or Mailgun is a better suggestion on 2016.